# Handle unauthorized 401 with passport

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I have an application based on the MEAN-Stack and I'm using passport to handle the Login/Logout etc.

So when the token now gets invalid and the user clicks a link inside my application, he only gets an "Unauthorized" into the console which looks like this:
[image]

So what I want is that a function gets called which clears the localStorage and redirects him to the login page but I don't know where I have to do this. This is my code:

**app.js**

```
//Port Number
const port = 3000;

//CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

//Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: false }));

//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//Importing Authentication
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/terminalType', terminalType);
app.use('/customer', customer);
app.use('/terminal', terminal);
app.use('/stock', stock);
app.use('/logbook', logbook);
app.use('/partner', partner);
app.use('/userrights', userrights);
app.use('/activity', activity);
app.use('/activityRecord', activityRecord);
app.use('/customerContract', customerContract);
app.use('/queenBeeRaces', queenBeeRaces);
app.use('/beecolony', beecolony);
app.use('/beehiveTypes', beehiveTypes);
app.use('/bugTypes', bugTypes);
app.use('/visitReporting', visitReporting);

//Calling Index-Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Ungültige Route!');
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

//Run server with nodemon
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
});
```

**passport.js**

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {

        User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data.user._id, (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                return done(err, false);
            } 

            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this in your Angular code as the user will be interacting with that. You can check for `HTTP 401` in your Angular app and if it encountered then you clear the `localStorage` using `localStorage.clear();` and redirect the user to a login page.

Comment: the whole login and authentication process is handled by passport so how should angular react to that? Where do i have to "hook in" and how?

Comment: I think the flow is like this:
1) user tries to log in  
2) Angular app requests token from Node.js
3) Angular app receives the token and user performs some actions.
4) User tries to perform some operation when the token has been expired and you see `HTTP 401` in the console(Angular app) (Angular app gets this data from Node.js app).

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: the 401 comes from express not from angular

Comment: Yes, it comes from Node.js app not from Angular app but you consume Node.js APIs in Angular app and Angular app will check for `HTTP 401`.

Comment: no passport will directly output its `Unauthorized` into console - no angular needed for that

Comment: Passport knows that the token has been expired because Passport itself is handling the login/logout functionality but it is being used by your Angular app. Your Angular app makes API request using that token and if the token has expired then your Angular app should receive `HTTP 401` (this is standard). Now you use this error to redirect the user to login page.

Comment: And if you consider a general front end app then at the time of token expiry, you should get new token instead of logging the user out of the system.

Comment: forget everything i said ;-) You were totally right. I had to handle that error inside my angular.component by adding a second path to my `subscribe()`. This is what solved my problem -> https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

Thanks a lot!